# Godot: how to make RigidBody2D move its child when moving?

Tags: game-physics, godot

I have simple scene in my game with the following structure:

```
Spaceship: RigidBody2D (type=Rigid)
  <4 Collision shapes - "walls" around>
  Item1: RigidBody2D (type=Rigid) 
  Item2: RigidBody2D (type=Static)
```

When I move parent RigidBody2D (Spaceship) I expect that all child items will move too (i.e. they will not change their relative coordinates).

But actually only Item2 (which is static) moves with parent, Item1 keeps its global coordinates, so it "move out" from parent RigidBody.

I've tried different combinations of RigidBody types and collision layers/masks, but no luck. Also I've tried to find something in docs, but docs for RigidBody2D do not describe how child physic objects will work during parent object movement.

Is there a way to keep child RigidBody2D in "relative" space of parent RigidBody2D?

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `RigidBody` is that it moves in response to the physics simulation. The [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html#description) specify that you shouldn't try to control the position directly (including via a parent transform):

> Please also keep in mind that physics bodies manage their own transform which overwrites the ones you set. So any direct or indirect transformation (including scaling of the node or its parent) will be visible in the editor only, and immediately reset at runtime.

If you want it to move according to its parent, why make it a `RigidBody` at all?

Consider using a [`KinematicBody`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html), or a `RigidBody` set to [kinematic mode](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html#enumerations).

You can also use [`Joints`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_joint.html#class-joint) to describe how two `RigidBodies` influence one another, though based on your comment it sounds like this still isn't exactly what you need.

Comment: Because I want them to interact with each other inside a isolated "room", and move that "room" on screen with all its contents. I understand that rigidbody's position shall not be modified directly, I just expected that child bodies may "inherit" forces/impulses applied to parent body somehow.

Comment: I see, so you want an isolated simulation within your larger scene. You might add that to your question, so someone else can provide a better answer.